# How long does it take to get to Budapest airport (BUD) by bus?

Tags: airport-transfer, buses, night-transport, budapest, bud

I want to know how long does the bus between Budapest city center and Budapest airport take.

I found [the official webpage](http://www.bud.hu/english/passengers/access_and_parking/by_public_transportation) (in english) of the airport where I can take a look at the timetables of the different buses that cover the route, but I don't know the estimated time of arrival to the airport.

I have to take a flight at 6:30 a.m. so I would be interested to know how long does it take for the buses that cover the route at that time of the day (the **200E** seems to be the one operating at that time). **Does any one know how long does it take to get to the airport from Kőbánya-Kispest metro station?**

Also I am completely open to suggestions of alternative ways of going to the airport at that time of the day.

Comment: The taxi ride took more than 45 minutes; so I can only guess the bus will be longer. There is no "highway" between the airport and the main city (unlike Amsterdam, for example) the route we took was on a single lane road, with plenty of traffic lights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikivoyage describes the logistics quite well](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Budapest#Get_in):

> Budapest Franz Liszt International Airport ... is the country's
>   largest airport, located about 16 km (10 mi) southeast of the city
>   centre.
>
> Budapest Airport is notoriously hard to get in and out of. While a
>   train connection between the city and the terminal has been built, it
>   only served Terminal 1, which is now defunct, and the currently used
>   Terminal 2 is an at least 10 mins drive away, on the very other side
>   of the airport. Public transportation between the city and airport
>   requires changing from bus to rail or metro and takes between 40 mins
>   to an hour. There is a single and long two-lane road connecting the
>   city and Ferihegy, and it unsurprisingly gets congested at peak times,
>   especially on the way to the airport, so bear this in mind and depart
>   for the airport early (at least an hour before the boarding time to
>   make sure you clear security).

Of course, you mention you're travelling at night, so traffic would be less. And you're wondering specifically about going from Kőbánya-Kispest. [Putting that into Google Maps at 4.30am](https://www.google.com.au/maps/dir/Budapest+Airport,+Budapest,+Hungary/K%C5%91b%C3%A1nya-Kispest+Vas%C3%BAt%C3%A1llom%C3%A1s,+Budapest,+Vasp%C3%A1lya+%C3%BAt+10,+1105+Hungary/@47.4424119,19.1668986,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m18!4m17!1m5!1m1!1s0x4741c1a4fe39860b:0x4ca4f6a650439aa1!2m2!1d19.2522958!2d47.4384587!1m5!1m1!1s0x4741c31fab6c0865:0xb256a1fdc51a7a2d!2m2!1d19.1495776!2d47.4640032!2m3!6e0!7e2!8j1440649800!3e0?hl=en), would seem to indicate **16-24** minutes travel time from Kőbánya-Kispest to the airport.  I played with it a bit and traffic seems to start to increase after 6am, but you should be at the airport well before that, especially if it's an international flight.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that website. The itinerary that you recommended me seems perfectly suitable.

Comment: @Adolfo no worries, glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is now slightly outdated -- I'd expect most people don't want to start from Kőbánya-Kispest but somewhere downtown. If so, the [direct bus](https://bkk.hu/en/airport-shuttle/) now starts at 3:40am, at 6:30AM I'd expect the roads to still be OK so it shouldn't take more than 35 minutes. It shouldn't -- but it will, at least until early 2021 I'd most certainly calculate 45 minutes because starting April 6, 2019 the south section of the M3 underground is out and it's replaced by buses and it'll slow down everything and the bus bridge and the airport bus overlap.